# Slides App Scripts - How to duplicate an image by keeping the scale

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'd like to duplicate an image on a first slide to another slide using Google Slide App Scripts.

For this, I get the data inside this image as a blob before inserting the blob in the next slide. The issue is that even when I set top, left, width and height values, I don't understand how I can keep the same scale (in my case I've cropped the image).

This is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

  var blop, width, height;

  slides[0].getImages().forEach(function(image){
    if(image.getTitle() == "image") {
      blop = image.getBlob()
      left = image.getLeft()
      top = image.getTop()
      width = image.getWidth()
      height = image.getHeight()
    }
  });

  slides[1].insertImage(blop, left, top, width, height)
}
```

You can see how it looks here:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1LlyHNbjcANWspPvJZedW9vgx9c9JHRD-kWOvXkwrDNo/edit?usp=sharing (viewer mode)

When I try to apply transformation the result is really different...

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that at Slides Service and Slides API, the crop of image cannot be used. This has already been reported. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113978819) So, I thought that in your situation, it might be required to duplicate the image including the crop information.
- In your script, `insertImage(blobSource, left, top, width, height)` is used. In this case, `blob` is the original image. By this, the crop information is not included. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In this case, I would like to propose to use `insertImage(image)`. The document of this method says as follows.

  > Inserts a copy of the provided [Image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image) on the page.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides[0].getImages().forEach(function(image){
    if(image.getTitle() == "image") {
      slides[1].refreshSlide();
      slides[1].insertImage(image);
      slides[1].refreshSlide();
    }
  });
}
```

#### Result:

When above modified script is used for your sample Google Slides, the following result is obtained.

[image]

- When I tested this modified script, I noticed an important point. When this script is used, it seems that `refreshSlide` might be required to be used. Because I confirmed that when `refreshSlide` is not used, the image without including the crop and coordinate information is copied.
- And also, In my environment, at most cases, the script worked fine. But, I noticed that when I tested several times, even when `refreshSlide` is used, there is the case that the image without including the crop and coordinate information is copied. So I thought that `insertImage(image)` might have a bug.

  - If in your environment, you have the same situation, how about reporting this to Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### References:

- [insertImage(blobSource, left, top, width, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertimageblobsource,-left,-top,-width,-height)
- [insertImage(image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertimageimage)
- [refreshSlide()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#refreshslide)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike,
Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.

After reading your message, I've followed your advice and I reported the bug to Google. I didn't receive a message saying that it was fixed but when I tried using this code
`slides[1].refreshSlide();
slides[1].insertImage(image);
slides[1].refreshSlide();`

Thanks again and I hope that it could help others!