# Replace an image in Google Slides with Apps Script with same croping

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to replace an image in a Google Slide by a smaller version of it (in terms of bytes).

The smaller image should be displayed exactly the same way than the older.

But when my original image was croped, I cannot reproduce it with the new one.

What I'm doing is simple (I'm using this [`replace` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#replaceimageurl,-crop))

```
  let image = page.getImages()[0];
  let newImageUrl = optimize(image.getContentUrl()); // API call to get an optimized image. newImage will have the same width and height
  image.replace(newImageUrl, true);
```

A visual example.
Here is my slide before (pay attention to the "Quick" logo at the bottom right corner)
[image]

And here is the result after replacing it (you can see that the bounding box is the same, it takes the same space in the slide, but the image itself is lower)
[image]

How can I reproduce the croping that I've initially done in my slide with that button [image] ?

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How can I reproduce the croping that I've initially done in my slide ?`. In your question, which is the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: A part of the bottom photo is cut by `optimize` function.

Comment: I've added some details in the post. The `optimize` function only returns a smaller version of the image (it takes a URL, returns a URL), but with the exact same widht and height. But I've initially used the "crop" button to cut off some of the top of the initial image, and I would like to reproduce that programmatically

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your upper and lower images are the sample input and output situation, respectively. In your situation, you manually cropped the image. And, you want to retrieve the cropped image using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in your goal, the cropped image is required to be reversible? Namely, you might delete the crop in the future?

Comment: Your understanding is correct! Yes, I might want to remove the crop in the future and so get back to the full version of the image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I might want to remove the crop in the future and so get back to the full version of the image.`, unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. By the way, can you explain your expected result of `let newImageUrl = optimize(image.getContentUrl());` and `image.replace(newImageUrl, true);`?

Comment: For example, are these answers useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256489/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040404/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309702/7108653

Comment: yep, definitely what I was looking for... so, not possible at the moment, I've starred the request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113978819

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

As mentioned in comments, crop properties are currently read-only, so this cannot be done. Here are possible workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256489, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040404, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309702.

#### Feature request:

There's a feature request in Issue Tracker. Anyone interested in this, consider starring it:

- [Why are Image Crop Properties read only](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113978819)